# updating selenium on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, selenium

I'm running selenium on linux (ubuntu) but I beleive it is an old version. Can someone tell me whether there's an easy way to update selenium on ubuntu using command line?  I couldn't find anything online explaining how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename>` will upgrade only specified package.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is easy to update. You either have it installed from apt or from pip. There are two ways, depending on how you installed the package

If you have installed selenium via pip (python)

```
pip install selenium --upgrade
```

If you have installed selenium via the package manager, then do

For Python 2.7

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade python-selenium
```

For Python 3.*

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade python3-selenium
```